# Create a new variable with 4 levels

Tags: r

I have two variables in my dataset and I want to combine `college_grad` and `sex` to create `sex_grad`. The levels should be as follows:

- Male Graduate
- Female Graduate
- Male Non-graduate
- Female Non-graduate

`collegegrad` has two levels:

- Yes
- No

`sex` has two levels:

- Male
- Female

How should I approach the required combination to support 4 levels? I know how to use `mutate` along with `ifelse`, but that creates only two variables.

Comment: `mutate(sex_grad = paste(college_grad, sex))` ?

Comment: Assuming `college_grad <- c("Graduate", "Non-Graduate")` and `sex <-
 c("Male", "Female")` won't `sex_grad <- paste(sex, college_grad)` do the trick ? If not, do share your `college_grad`, `sex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `paste` instead of `ifelse`.

```
college_grad = c("Graduate", "Non-graduate")
sex = c("Male", "Female")
df <- expand.grid(college_grad = college_grad, sex = sex)
df$sex_grad <- with(df, paste(sex, college_grad))
df

#   college_grad    sex            sex_grad
# 1     Graduate   Male       Male Graduate
# 2 Non-graduate   Male   Male Non-graduate
# 3     Graduate Female     Female Graduate
# 4 Non-graduate Female Female Non-graduate
```

---

**Edit**: This one corresponds to your edit.

```
college_grad = c("Yes", "No")
sex = c("Male", "Female")
df <- expand.grid(college_grad = college_grad, sex = sex)
df$sex_grad <- with(df, ifelse(college_grad == "Yes", paste(sex, "Graduate"), paste(sex, "Non-graduate")))
df
```

Answer (score 0):

By combine you might mean a couple of things. Without a dataset to work with and an example of what output you want it's a bit harder to answer your question.

If you want to add the columns together, and keep all existing columns, then:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    mpg_am = mpg + am 
  )
```

If you want to drop existing columns then replace `mutate` with `transmute`.

If you want to collect variables into columns then:

```
mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("car_names") %>% 
  gather(variable, obs, -car_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `interaction`. With the example data of @hpesoj626:

```
college_grad <- c("Graduate", "Non-graduate")
sex <- c("Male", "Female")

df <- expand.grid(college_grad = college_grad, sex = sex)
df$sex_grad <- interaction(df$sex, df$college_grad, sep = ' & ')
```

The result:

```
> df
  college_grad    sex              sex_grad
1     Graduate   Male       Male & Graduate
2 Non-graduate   Male   Male & Non-graduate
3     Graduate Female     Female & Graduate
4 Non-graduate Female Female & Non-graduate
```